# calling a dervied method from a parent class c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have `ToString()` defined in a parent class in a way that applies to nearly all of its descendent classes, which usually involves calling a property called Name. This property is redefined in the child classes.

However, this doesn't work because the Name property from the parent class is always used, even when I redefine it in the descendent class.

Here is an example:

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bar n = new Bar();
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return MyName;
        }

        public string MyName { get { return "foo"; }}
    }

    class Bar : Foo
    {
        public new string MyName { get { return "bar";  }}
    }
}
```

The output of this example is `foo` but I want it to be `bar`.

What am I doing wrong? Or am I just misunderstanding a fundamental aspect of inheritance in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because `ToString()` is [*virtual*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx).

Add the `virtual` keyword to your base property, and change `new` to `override` in the derived property.

Comment: Yup, I didn't understand virtual. Now I do. Thanks!